# A proof that $1=2$. May I know why it’s false?

Tags: derivatives, fake-proofs

im not good at formatting. May I know why it’s false

$x^2= x+x+x+\ldots(x\; \text{times})$

apply derivative on both sides

$=> \frac{d}{dx}(x^2)=\frac{d}{dx}(x+x+x+\ldots(x\; \text{times}))$

$=> 2x=1+1+1+\ldots(x\; \text{times})$

$=> 2x=x$

$=> 2=1$

Comment: How do you make sense of $x+x+x+..(x\text{ times})$ when $x$ is not a whole number?

Comment: But the real problem is that your right-hand derivative has not considered the "$x$ times". The right-hand side depends on that; so the derivative should do something with it.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/237817/264

Comment: @ZevChonoles Thanks.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Thanks

Comment: The correct "proof" can be fouind [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/38856/jokes-in-the-sense-of-littlewood-examples/39950#39950).

Comment: Also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/where-is-the-flaw-in-this-argument-of-a-proof-that-1-2-derivative-of-repeated

Comment: You can't differentiate a function that isn't continuous since it isn't define when $x$ isn't a whole number, remember, non-continuous means non-differentiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add '$x$', $x$ number of times without knowing what $x$ exactly is. Hence the differentiation on the RHS has no real meaning.

This fails for many cases like:

$1)$ '$x$' is not an integer.

$2)$ Dependency of $x$ on $x$ which you are not considering when differentiating on RHS.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked twice or thrice already. Two problems might be pointed out

$(1)$ "$x$ times" is ill-defined for non integer values of $x$; and even so

$(2)$ "$x$ times" is also a function of $x$, which you're ignoring